# Calling variables to sub function?

Tags: php, function, variables, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I have a post variable and I want to use it my sub function. How can I do that ? When I tried it says "Undefined Variable".

**Controller**

```
public function getSingle($slug){

    $post = Post::where('slug',$slug)->first();

    $related_categories_posts = Post::whereHas('categories',function ($query){
        $query->where('category_name', $post->categories->category_name);
    })
    ->take(3)
    ->get();



    return view('frontend.single')
            ->with('post',$post)
            ->with('related_categories_posts',$related_categories_posts);
}
```

Any advice ?

Comment: I recommend you to fix your code indentation issues.

Comment: You didn't `use`.

Comment: @revo seems so, I was couldn't find it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass this variable to the function by using `use` as described in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

```
$related_categories_posts = Post::whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($post){
    $query->where('category_name', $post->categories->category_name);
})
```

Comment: it works, thanks. I didin't know that